# Error when I try to run test on google chrome using Java with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, module

I want to ask if someone can help me? I got stuck when executing this automatic test. It gives me the errors from the 2 pictures attached above and I can't find any solution. Who has encountered this situation before can help  me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvhhf.png)com/MNzrN.png)

Comment: First line in Java class is always `package packageName`, which is missing in your class.

Answer (score 0):

1. File / New Project / with selected option Use default JRE (1.8)
   [image: new project]
2. convert the project to Maven project
   [image: convert to maven project]
3. add selenium dependency

[image: selenium dependency]

1. in src folder create a package, name it for example *selenium*
   [image: package]
2. create a source folder in the project, name it for example *resources*
   [image: source folder]
3. save chromedriver.exe in the resources folder and refresh the project
4. in src folder create a package, name it for example *tests* and a class let's *Example1*
5. download source to get all required jars
   [image: download sources]
6. enter the code:

selenium.ChromeDriverSetup class:

```
package selenium;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class ChromeDriverSetup {
    
    public static String chromedriverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";   

    public static WebDriver startChromeDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

tests.Example1:

```
package tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class Example1 extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
        
    }
    
}
```

7. run Example1